# slack API users.identity not working

Tags: python, api, slack, slack-api

I am trying to get my python slack bot to work. I want to get the info of the user who is trying to make API calls using `users.identity` API. However, I was unable to make it to work.

Any tips and idea why?

This is the error I get.

[image: this is the error i get]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work on https://api.slack.com/methods/users.identity/test. But if you create an "app/script" where you can authenticate and then request with https://slack.com/api/users.identity?token=xxx you will get a valid response for the logged in person. With User Name,User id and Team id

Comment: i am using slackclient. Can you be more specified about authentication? I tried https://slack.com/api/users.identity?token=<my token> on browser wont work, and I also tried slack_client.api_call("users.identity", token="...")) on python still wont work

Comment: this is the message i got '{u'needed': u'identity.basic', u'provided': u'identify,read,post,client,apps', u'ok': False, u'error': u'missing_scope'}'

Comment: You will need to do this step https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth to get an access token. in https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth#appending_scopes you will need to add this scope to the oauth request users.identity.